# Disabling submit/post button if inputs empty jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I have been looking all over but did not find anything that worked for me. I am trying to prevent users from sending incomplete forms. I have disabled "submit" by default, and the intent is to remove the "disable" attribute if all inputs have been provided. For some reason the submit button is still disable. I believe the code below should work, but i guess i might be missing something.

FYI - I am using Jquery datepicker and timepicker to let users select dates and times.

Would anyone be able to help a newbie?

```html
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.field input').keyup(function() {
 
         var empty = false;
         $('.field input').each(function() {
             if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                 empty = true;
             }
         });
 
         if (empty) {
             $('.actions input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
         } else {
             $('.actions input').removeAttr('disabled');
         }
     });
 });
 
</script>


  <div>

 <form class="form" name="frm1"  method="POST"> 
 
     <div class='field'>
       <label for="datepicker">Day:</label>
       <input type="text" name="txtDate" id="datepicker"> </br>
     </div>
     
     <div class='field'>
       <label for="fromtime">From:</label>
       <input type="text" name="txtStartTime" id="fromtime"></br>
     </div>
       
     <div class='field'>
       <label for="totime">To:</label>
       <input type="text" name="txtEndTime" id="totime"></br>
     </div>
     
     <div class='droppies'>
          <label for="level">Level</label>
      <select name="level" id="level">
    <option selected value='%'></option>
    <option value='Beginner'>Beginner</option>
    <option value='Intermediate'>Intermediate</option>
    <option value='Advanced'>Advanced</option>
    <option value='%'>Any levels</option>
    
      </select>
     </div>
     
     <div class='actions'>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search" disabled="disabled"> 
     </div>
    </form>
 

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add required to the html input.

```
<input type="text" name="txtDate" id="datepicker" required>
```

Comment: Simple ... but IT WORKS and does exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thanks a lot Alden!

Comment: @YvanNasr you have to realize that this method is not a javascript method. it is proposing an alternative to your method, but does not solve the problem you are encountering.

Comment: It does solve the problem. It does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're using IE? Because attr disabled will not work there, you need to use:

```
$('.actions input').prop('disabled', true);
```

And

```
$('.actions input').prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that but it does work. Still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is with the type of listener you are implementing. you are ONLY trying to change the state of your disabled button when a keyup is fired on your inputs. If you are changing your date using clicks, which is the intention of your jquery timepicker plugin, then you will NOT trigger a check on validation status.

You should use watch for any changes in your input elements.

```
$('.field input').change(function(){ ... logic ...});
```

Answer (score -1):

> Use `.filter` to get the count of the elements having value as `''`

Use `onSelect` in DatePicker options to test the validations on date select.

**Note:** Use [`.prop` over `.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/). `$(SELECTOR).on('input')` could be used. *The DOM [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event is fired synchronously when the value of an `<input> or <textarea>` element is changed*

Try this:

```js
function test() {
  var len = $('.field :input').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).val();
  }).length;
  $('.actions input').prop('disabled', !!len);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: test
  });
  $('.field input').keyup(test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <form class="form" name="frm1" method="POST">
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="datepicker">Day:</label>
      <input type="text" name="txtDate" id="datepicker">
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="fromtime">From:</label>
      <input type="text" name="txtStartTime" id="fromtime">
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="totime">To:</label>
      <input type="text" name="txtEndTime" id="totime">
    </div>
    <div class='droppies'>
      <label for="level">Level</label>
      <select name="level" id="level">
        <option selected value='%'></option>
        <option value='Beginner'>Beginner</option>
        <option value='Intermediate'>Intermediate</option>
        <option value='Advanced'>Advanced</option>
        <option value='%'>Any levels</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search" disabled="disabled">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/8w8v9/1242/)